# dimple Legend scroll option

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

Legends get hidden due to more number of values. 
So I am trying to add **Pagination** or drop down button option in the legend - dimple. 
Suppose if there 20 legends, i need to show 4 option/value at a time. So they can click **Pagination** or **drop down button** to see the next available options/values.
 I couldn't find the correct resource - how to create it. This is the code for dimple chart.
res.result will get data from the function

```
var PieChartWidth = "100%", PieChartHeight = 300;
var Piesetboundxaxis = "13.79%",Piesetboundyaxis = "16.66%",
Piesetboundwidth = "68.96%",Piesetboundheight = "66.66%";
var Pielegendxaxis = "71.66%",Pielegendyaxis = "24.16%",
Pielegendwidth = "13.79%",Pielegendheight = "66.66%%";
var verticalPaddingsize = 2;

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#"+chartid, PieChartWidth, PieChartHeight);
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, res.result);
myChart.setBounds(Piesetboundxaxis, Piesetboundyaxis, Piesetboundwidth, Piesetboundheight)
myChart.addMeasureAxis("p", "result");
myChart.addSeries(xaxisname, dimple.plot.pie);
var myLegend = myChart.addLegend(Pielegendxaxis, Pielegendyaxis, Pielegendwidth, Pielegendheight, "left");
myLegend.verticalPadding = verticalPaddingsize;
myLegend.fontSize = Chartfontsize;
myLegend.fontFamily = chartfontname;
myChart.draw();[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain the problem you are having more clearly. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.